# Storage removable virus (like hidden)

Tags: flash, command, hidden, recovery, virus

my hdd external have virus like hidden but not hidden.
i have storage size and i can recovery my hdd but command unhidden not working .

how can i fix without recovery ? Here is a [link](http://www.uploadax.com/images/35943795804004637922.jpg).

Since I'm seeng many people having their files hidden by flash drive viruses

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but that appears to be data corruption. If you know what type of files they were you could try changing the extensions on those files and see if they open correctly. For example if those used to be Word documents you could rename them to file1.doc or file1.docx depending on how you saved them. You can also run a disk check on the drive by going to the Start Menu and clicking on Computer. Under Removable Devices you can right click on your external drive and select "Properties." Under the "Tools" tab there is a section called "Error checking." Click on "Check" to begin error checking. Depending on the size of your drive and how many errors it finds this might take a while.

If you are sure it is a virus though scan your drive first with something like Malwarebytes.